# QTcpServer synchronous connection

Tags: qt, qtcpserver

I was trying to use the synchronous connection mechanism of QTcpServer to implement a server. 
My code is very simple one. PFB.

```
//////

MainScreen::MainScreen(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainScreen)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    server = new QTcpServer();

}


int MainScreen::waitForConnection()
{
    bool timeOut = 0;

    if (server->listen(QHostAddress("192.168.70.30"), 10000))
    {

        quint16 port = server->serverPort();
        qDebug() << "Server : "<< (server->serverAddress()).toString() << "Port : "<< port;
        server->waitForNewConnection(-1, &timeOut);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

//main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainScreen w;

    w.waitForConnection();

    return a.exec();

}
```

And I'm trying to connect to the server from a Linux client application(C).  Unfortunately I'm not getting any connection in my server. Do I need to do something else to work on synchronous connection? Thanks in advance

PFB result of netstat

netstat -np TCP

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State

TCP    127.0.0.1:62908        127.0.0.1:62909        ESTABLISHED

TCP    127.0.0.1:62909        127.0.0.1:62908        ESTABLISHED

TCP    192.168.70.89:62817    10.47.1.10:49224       ESTABLISHED

TCP    192.168.70.89:62924    10.47.1.101:3128       ESTABLISHED

TCP    192.168.70.89:63209    10.47.1.101:3128       TIME_WAIT

TCP    192.168.70.89:63213    10.47.1.101:3128       TIME_WAIT

TCP    192.168.70.89:63264    10.47.1.101:3128       TIME_WAIT

TCP    192.168.70.89:63265    10.47.1.101:3128       TIME_WAIT

TCP    192.168.70.89:63266    10.47.1.11:8014        CLOSE_WAIT

TCP    192.168.70.89:63267    111.221.112.54:995     TIME_WAIT

TCP    127.0.0.1:62908        127.0.0.1:62909        ESTABLISHED

Comment: How do you try to connect to your server? What port do you use? The server listens on "192.168.70.30", yes. But on a random port.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to the server through port '10000'

Comment: fleet's advice is good. Try QHostAddress::Any. Or try 127.0.0.1 and see if you can connect locally. Your code is good and should work. I suppose when you tried, your machine really had 192.168.70.30? Because when you used netstat it was  192.168.70.89.

Comment: Now Iam using QHostAddress::Any, and my server is on 192.168.70.89. The netstat result is not showing my port.

Comment: The code is good. I copy/pasted your code, just to be sure. I had no problems to connect using telnet. Looks more like your network. Whatever the problem is, it is not the lines above.

Comment: Change netstat -np TCP to netstat -nlp TCP.

Comment: Yea...I tried to connect using putty from the same PC. That's working..But not from other PCs in the network..I'm new to this network related things

Comment: This is more or less the end of this 'thread'. Even for you your code works then. Very hard if not impossible from here to debug your local network configuration. :-)

Comment: OK thanks...dono how to solve this...

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

- On the server, is it actually listening for incoming connections? Run netstat -lt on linux or netstat -ta on windows and check if the port is open on a listening status.
- Use QHostAddress::Any rather than a specific address on the host, in case it has a problem with that address.

Addition: You have to run netstat in windows with the command netstat -nap TCP so it shows the listening ports. But since you can connect to your network server locally then that shows it is working. It looks like you're running under windows. If so have you tried to disable window's firewall? If you're running an anti-virus, try disabling that too in case it's blocking connections from outside the machine. Lastly, make sure the machines can see each other through ping.

Comment: I have added netstat result....I couldn't find my port in that. And I tried with  QHostAddress::Any without success.